# How can I call function before the component in if statement?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can I call function before the component in if statement? I have syntax error with this.

Here are the codes:

```
                  <AccordionDetails> 
                    {answers.map((a) => (
                      
                      Number(a.SoruID) === Number(soru.SoruID) ?
                      getAnswerCount(a.SoruID, a.Id),
                      <Typography>
                      {a.TextCevap} kullanicilar :{cevapSayisi}
                      </Typography> 
                      :null
                    ))}
                     
                  </AccordionDetails>
```

I'm stackoverflow newbie, I used screenshot instead of the code before, sorry for this.

Comment: Why do you want to call a function? I would create a solution for you, but I can't copy the code from the image :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Well, the syntax error is pretty clear: In a conditional expression (ternary), you must have one question mark followed by one colon. If you're having issues with your expression being divided incorrectly, use parentheses `()` to enclose the parts of the expression.

Comment: I should have copied and pasted the codes, sorry. Anyway, thank you for your hard work @Konrad and writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the full syntax, if the short syntax does not suit you.

```
<AccordionDetails>
  {answers.map((a) => {
    if (Number(a.SoruID) === Number(soru.SoruID)){
       const totalAnswers = getAnswerCount(a.SoruID, a.Id);
       return (
         <Typography>
           {a.TextCevap} ..... {totalAnswers}
         </Typography>
       );
    }
    return null;
  })
</AccordionDetails>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

```
<AccordionDetails>
  {answers.map((a) => (
     Number(a.SoruID) === Number(soru.SoruID))
       (
         getAnswerCount(a.SoruID, a.Id),
         <Typography>
           {a.TextCevap} ..... {totalAnswers}
         </Typography>
       )
    : null
  ))}
</AccordionDetails>
```